# Font Face rendering of boxes around text produces ugly result if text is not placed in separated lines

Tags: font-lock

Following behavior observed while running Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon with Emacs 28.2.1 installed from source and with via emacs GUI made following changes to ~/.emacs:

```
 '(default ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans" :foundry "PfEd" :slant normal :weight normal :height 120 :width normal))))
 '(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face ((t (:inherit font-lock-comment-face :foreground "SeaGreen4" :box (:line-width 3 :color "yellow" :style pressed-button) :weight extra-bold :family "Liberation Mono"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#007700" :box (:line-width 4 :color "light gray" :style released-button) :weight normal :height 130 :family "Liberation Mono"))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#119911")))))
```

[image: 01]  [image: 2]  [image: 3]  [image: 4]

There is a problem with rendering of boxes around the text as can be seen in the above pictures. First picture shows the comments in separate lines. Second picture shows the comments after the empty line between the comments was deleted.

Scrolling forth and back does not change the picture; the box in the upper line stays without the right shadow line. The third picture shows how it looks like after adding an empty line between the comments. Now with scrolling the comments out of the visible area and back brings the right look back again (fourth picture), but in case of no separated lines as in the second picture scrolling out of view and back does not help.

Is it a bug worth to be fixed? Or is there any good reason why it can't be fixed I am not aware of? I can understand that the bottom/upper lines may collide, so it would be necessary to increase line spacing if boxes are used, but don't see any reason why the right shadow line is not rendered.

Is there a way to make it work as expected? Some additional specification fixing the observed unexpected behavior? Can you reproduce what I am speaking about?

Comment: Looks like a bug and bugs are always worth reporting. As for the crash, it's not clear from your description whether it was a crash or a hang: was Emacs waiting for something else? If you can get more information, that is even more worthy of a bug report. FWIW, I run Emacs for weeks on end and although it has become unresponsive a couple of times over the past year, I find it very reliable. And note that I'm running upstream, unreleased, "unstable" versions most of the time (something I don't recommend BTW: "do as I say, not as I do")

Comment: Emacs hasn't crashed on me since X11 was new on "free unixes".

Comment: Why are you running 6 instances anyway?

Comment: You should update your question with what OS, window system, and toolkit you're using as that will aid in getting help.

Comment: @nega Why I was running 6 instances? Just because it is possible. I haven't found yet my way to cope with frames, windows, buffers and instances and while learning I am jumping from one subject to the other, multiple approaches at the same time. Using emacs as a better Terminal with copy//paste, as a Lisp interpreter, Python code editor ... having an eye on tutorials, lists with keyboard mappings, etc. ... Just beginner confusion and fun as SciTE I was using up to now allowed only one instance. Still not all the features from SciTE made available on emacs ... will be a longer way to go ...

Comment: @nega : question updated. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @NickD : no idea if it was a crash or a hang ... sorry, ... don't know the difference between a crash and a hang. The other instances were running and closing ok. Isn't there only one emacs (server) instance which drives all the other as new windows experienced ones? Like it is the case for gnome-terminal?

Comment: By the way: SciTE highlighting was able to distinguish between in single quotes and double quotes embedded string literals in both variants: single quoted and triple quoted. That made it possible to define 4 different font properties for the 4 different string literal variants. I will probably ask another question about how to get this in emacs, maybe with differentiating between byte and Unicode strings too. Searching the Internet did not help yet. It seems that there are not many high skilled users of emacs.

Comment: One question per post, please. You're asking about ugly rendering and you're asking about a crash. Different dogs.